# Drop down list in grid view

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to create a drop down list in grid view? Drop down list with 2 value which is pending and cancel. Below HTML code is part of my code

```
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order Status">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("OrderStatus")%>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
              <asp:DropDownlist ID="ddlOrderStatus" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("OrderStatus") %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: _"Below HTML code is without drop down list"_ Then add it and tell us what problems you had to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to bind data to drop down list in grid view

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order Status" SortExpression="Order Status">
<EditItemTemplate>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOrderStatus" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%#Eval("OrderStatus") %>'>
   <asp:ListItem Text="---Select---"/></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="pending"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="Cancel"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("OrderStatus") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```